# Xaml switch between TextBlock and TextBox

Tags: wpf, performance, textbox, focus, textblock

I've noticed that TextBoxes are very slow and create performance issues when the `Text` is changed dynamically by code (I need to change the `Text` continuosly to 10-15 TextBoxes at the same time), so, as a workaround, I've created a custom control with a `TextBlock` and a `TextBox`:

> The `TextBlock` is used in almost all time.
>   The `TextBox` is used **only** when I need to edit the `Text` inside the control with keyboard.

My solution is to change the template and use the TextBox when the control is focused:

(`Value` is a `string` Dependency Property)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">

    <Setter Property="Value" Value="Val"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Value}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <TextBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                     Text="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But when I click on the control nothing happens.
I think that the problem is that the "focus state" is passed to the internal TextBox, and the control loses the "focus state".

There is a better way to create a custom "TextBox" control like this, or a way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a custom control for this, that's just adding unnecessary overhead. What you're trying to create is still a TextBox, with all the usual behavior of a TextBox (focus etc). All you need to do is change the template to a TextBlock when it's not in focus:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="Hello World" />
    <TextBox Text="Goodbye World" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: we have the same solution in our project. but the problem with this solution is the caret position when the textbox got focus. the caret should be on the mouseposition. But instead it is always on index 0.
setting the CaretIndex in the GotFocus-Event with the help of GetCharacterIndexFromPoint does not work. GetCharacterIndexFromPoint always returns "-1". Did you came up with any solutions for that? @Mark

Comment: @PandaPlayer if you want that functionality then the control has to be a TextBox at the moment you click it. Easiest solution is to change the above from a regular Trigger to a MultiTrigger with conditions `IsMouseOver=false` and `IsFocused=false`. If you want it to still look like a TextBlock when then mouse is over it then you can add another MultiTrigger for `IsMouseOver=true` and `IsFocused=false`, and in that trigger set BorderThickness to 0. It will need a few other minor tweaks to get it 100% perfect (eg removing the internal margin) but that will get you pretty close to what you need.

Comment: Very good Idea! Thanky you very much. I will try this